# Ionic 2 select: remove selected option

Tags: ionic2

I'm using ion-select component in a form, but got a problem: if users selects one option, but then wanna remove it, it doesn't give the option. I could add a `<ion-option>` with blank value, but think it wouldn't be nice. Is there a better way to solve that?

EDIT: 
This is how my select options looks right now:
[image]

If the users selects one option and then changes his mind and don't wanna select any option, it doesn't seems pretty clear the way he can do that. Even if add a "Remove Option" with blank value, it still looks like an option, doesn't seems nice to me. With a traditional select, the blank option without a text seems pretty intuitive. But in this case, I was thinking in something like a " (X) Remove selected", near to "Cancelar/Confirmar" options in the footer, or something like that. Any ideas? 
Ps: also, ion-option seems to strip any html tag I put on my option, so it keeps pretty tough to format my "select none" option

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to the question?

Comment: how do you wanna remove the selected option?

Comment: Edited the question with some details!

Comment: you would need to create custom component for this. Would that work?

Comment: @SandeepSharma yeah, I could do that, but I hoped Ionic 2 provided some more elegant solution with ion-select :/

Comment: Why can't the user hit cancel if he changes his mind?

Comment: @Ari he can. But for example, if he sets and clicks "confirm" (setting the option), then he goes back to that select trying to remove the option set previously, he can't ('cause in that case cancel doesn't set the option selected as empty, it just remains as it was before)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@sonu's solution will work if the user wants to click on the `ion-select` again and chose a `select-nothing` option, but I don't find that a pleasant experience.

An alternative way to get to what you want is to use a small clear button next to your `ion-select`, which appears only when user has already selected something:

```
  <ion-label>Options</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="option">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>

  <div *ngIf="option=='m' || option=='f'">
    <ion-label> {{option}} </ion-label>
    <ion-button  (click)='removeSelection()'>
       <ion-icon name='close'></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </div>
```

Where `removeSelection()` is a function that changes the selection to `"No selection"`, perhaps by setting `this.option=null`.

Of course, you can style this button as you wish. You may also want to look at ionic [chips](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/chip/Chip/). In particular, delete chips are one way to implement your intention.

[image: Ionic chips]

Comment: This is exactly what I was talking about! Thanks so much for your time. Nice answer =)

Comment: Awesome answer! Just wanted to add on the method call using  
`removeSelection("value passed here"){valuepassed.valueAccessor._text = "" }`  worked for me using the ngModel directive.

Answer (score 3):

To trigger a function that handles the cancel selection you can just use the **ionCancel** attribute like this

```
  <ion-select okText="Select" cancelText="Clear"formControlName="selectionValue" (ionCancel)="clearSelection()">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let selection of selections" [value]="selection.value">{{selection.description}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

And in the code just implement the function you declared; in this case **clearSelection()**

```
clearSelection() {
    this.myModel.selectedValue = null;
}
```

Now every time you press the clear button your function will be triggered

Documentation: [ion-select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/)

Answer (score 2):

I had a slight different requirement - after selecting an option and clicking on OK button, the selected value should be used in function called by ionChange and then selected option in ion-select should get deselected. I tried various solutions mentioned in various sites but none worked. Even the working solution in plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/2KVqL2ecColaXgzAfxWI?p=preview where the ngModel value is set to null didn't work for me.
So I tried myself different things and one them did the trick. Below is the way that worked for me:-

In HTML I have used #languageSelect as template reference variable for ViewChild in ion-select

```
<ion-label>Select Language</ion-label>
<ion-select #languageSelect (ionChange)="langSelected($event)">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let lang of languages" [value]="lang">{{lang}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

And in ts file it is used as

```
@ViewChild('languageSelect') languageSelect: Select;
```

In langSelected() it is cleared after doing the needful.

```
langSelected(value) {
 //used the value as required
 ...
 ...
 this.languageSelect.setValue(''); // This is clearing the selected option in ion-select
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better way to have option with blank value.You can use code as per ionic [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/)

example:

```
<ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
    <ion-option value="">Select Gender</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Or you can add any event for selection clear.

Comment: Added some details and a screenshot. Thanks!